# Apache does not start in xampp even thou i don't have conflicting port

Tags: apache, xampp

After i finished installing the xampp software i went ahead to lunch Apache from the control panel but it would not start and it does not seem to bring up why it's not starting. I changed the port from 80 to 85 even thou i don't have a conflicting port but still it's not starting. Please check the screenshot below to let me know why and how to solve it.

[image]

Comment: if you press on start you get any error? can you please click on Logs and give us the latest error log in this file to can trace the error...

Comment: To little information to help.  What do the logs say?